# Dynamic dropdown in Google sheets using formula

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have a Google sheet where I have 2 sheets **To Do** and the **Config** respectively

In **To Do** sheet the D2 column is dependent on C2 column and D3 column is dependent on C3 column and so on.

The dynamic options are determined from the config sheet and by using formula

I have tried with `=SPLIT(JOIN(",",Config!$1:$1),C2,false)` and then `=transpose(filter(Config!A4:A20,(INDEX(Config!A4:G20,,1+COUNTA(SPLIT(H5,","))))=TRUE))`

This formula results in overflow #REF error. (H5 cell)

**I must be able to expand the config sheet and it must be scalable to any number of rows and columns**

**When All is selected I must be able to get all drop downs (The cell values of A in all projects)**  Config!B3, Config!B4 and so on, Hence when there is tick in B3, all the projects would have A3 ("SORT") as an option in drop down.

You can make a copy of the sheet here
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A2Snz_ivGwBEvz__HY9Ee9DXve5Yosl7ZrPohncO-Ek/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how you want the slicer to work?  Is it meant to limit the projects being displayed, to only those from the selected sub-group?  So if you select ALL, you want all projects to show?  That seems to be what it is doing now, correct? Or are you intending something else?  Like that all sub-groups should be available in column D for all projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this formula in sheet To Do, cell J2:

`=INDEX(IF(C2:C="","",TRIM(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(C2:C,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(Config!C1:M1&"♠️"&QUERY(IF(Config!C3:M + Config!B3:B, Config!A3:A&"♦", ),,9^9)),"♠️"),2,),"♦"))))`

It will populate possible answers from sheet Config.

[image]

Change:

- `Config!C1:M1`
- `Config!C3:M`
- `Config!B3:B`

to your ranges.

#ToDo #1

Show all values if PROJECT has empty value:

`=INDEX(IFERROR(IF(C2:C="",SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("❤️",1,Config!A3:A),"❤️"),TRIM(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(C2:C,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(Config!C1:M1&"♠️"&QUERY(IF(Config!C3:M + Config!B3:B, Config!A3:A&"♦", ),,9^9)),"♠️"),2,""),"♦")))))`

Comment: Could you please help me to change the above formula to show ALL selected items Config! sheet when C2 is empty. The current formula will show empty when C column is empty.

Comment: @CodeGuy, please try: `=INDEX(IFERROR(IF(C2:C="",SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("❤️",1,Config!A3:A),"❤️"),TRIM(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(C2:C,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(Config!C1:M1&"♠️"&QUERY(IF(Config!C3:M + Config!B3:B, Config!A3:A&"♦", ),,9^9)),"♠️"),2,""),"♦")))))`

Comment: =INDEX(IFERROR(IF(C2:C="",TRANSPOSE(QUERY(Config!A1:AZ,"Select A where B = true",0)),TRIM(SPLIT(VLOOKUP(C2:C,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(Config!C1:M1&"♠️"&QUERY(IF(Config!C3:M + Config!B3:B, Config!A3:A&"♦", ),,9^9)),"♠️"),2,""),"♦"))))) I modified to this. Is this efficient in terms of speed?

Comment: @CodeGuy, for speed up, I'd make a dictionary with this formula, and then use it with vlookup to return values on main sheet. Not sure of it, though.

Comment: Anyways this is fine as of now. Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not clear how you'll use column H and column I, but your current SPLIT formula in column H has the chance of splitting into more than two columns,as you see with H5.  Splitting on "Project #1 would split "Project #10, Project #11, Project #12" repeatedly, and probably not the way you want.

Changing that formula to:

```
=SPLIT(JOIN(",",Config!$1:$1),C2&",",false)
```

to include the comma after the project number - C2&"," - should force it to only split once, into two columns.

This should solve your first issue.

For your second issue, using the slicer, I have a clarification question, which I'll add as a comment below your original question.

**EDIT #1:**

I see that column H is used to be able to count off which column in CONFIG a certain project is in.  Would an easier way to do this be to do a MATCH in CONFIG!A1:1 for the project name?  Then you might not need the existing columns H and I at all.

So in 'To Do'!J2, if you replace your current formula with this:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Config!A$1:A$17,(INDEX(Config!A$1:G$17,,MATCH(C2,Config!$A$1:$1,0) ))=TRUE))
```

that would eliminate the need for H and I?  That formula can be dragged down.

**EDIT #2**

I revised the above formula, to replace what you have in J2, as follows:

```
=IF(LEN(C2),TRANSPOSE(
   IF($G$1,
     SORT(UNIQUE(Config!$A$4:$A)),
     IFERROR(FILTER(Config!A$1:A$17,(INDEX(Config!A$1:G$17,,MATCH(C2,Config!$A$1:$1,0) ))=TRUE),"")
   )),"")
```

And I tried a tickbox in G1 to perhaps replace your slicer (see image below).  If G1 is checked, all sub-groups are available to the project, in column D.  If unchecked, only those for which the project is assigned, in Config, are available.  That's my understanding of what you might want.

[image]

**EDIT #3**

Sorry for my misunderstanding.  Looking at the Config sheet more closely, that should have been obvious.  Try this formula in 'To Do'!H2, and drag down:

```
=IF(LEN(C2),TRANSPOSE(
   SORT(UNIQUE(
     {FILTER(Config!A$3:A,Config!B$3:B);
      IFERROR(FILTER(Config!A$1:A$17,(INDEX(Config!A$1:G$17,,MATCH(C2,Config!$A$1:$1,0) ))=TRUE),"") }
   ))),"")
```

It checks the row has data in C2, then it filters the sub-categories in Config, to pick all the ones that are checked under the first "ALL" column, and then it adds on the unique ones that are checked for that specific project.  It removes any duplicates, sorts them alphabetically, and then transposes them, to go across in one row.  The result is the data validation values for that specifc project, in 'To Do'.

Comment: That's the crude way I did. I just want this to be working somehow and it must be scalable when I add more rows and cols to config sheet

Comment: Ignore the slicer

Comment: I'm not sure what issue is still outstanding - doesn't the above work, even if the number of projects, or the enumber of sub-groups, expands?

Comment: Sorry I didnt mean the ALL in G1 cell, The one I was referring was Config!B3, Config!B4 and so on, Hence when there is tick in B3, all the projects would have A3 ("SORT") as an option in drop down. Could you help me with that?

Comment: See my updated answer, EDIT #3.  How's that?